# Java's "lookingAt" regex function?

Tags: java, regex, go

I'm trying to port [this script](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/AsYouTypeFormatter.java) from Java to Go. This script uses the [`lookingAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--) function in several places. It seems this function is just meant to check if the string begins with a string that matches the pattern

> Attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning of the region, against the pattern.
> Like the matches method, this method always starts at the beginning of the region; unlike that method, it does not require that the entire region be matched.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.
>
> Returns:
> true if, and only if, a prefix of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Is there a similar function available in Go's [`regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) package (I don't see something similar), and if not, how would one implement it?

Right now, my best implementation looks like this:

```golang
regex := "ThePrefix"
stringToBeMatched := "ThePrefix-The rest of the string"

pattern := regexp.MustCompile(regex)
idxs := pattern.FindStringIndex(stringToMatch)

lookingAt := len(idxs) > 0 && idxs[0] == 0
```

But I feel like this could be improved.

Comment: That's not how regular expressions work, so it's not how the regexp engine is implemented. You could do it with a whole bunch of nested `()?`s but it'd be a mess.

Comment: Go doesn’t (seem to) have an equivalent of Java’s Matcher. Do you always want the lookingAt condition to be true? Could you give a small example of what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm porting this class: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/AsYouTypeFormatter.java to GoLang. The `lookingAt` function is being used in the `narrowDownPossibleFormats` function.

Comment: @NathanF I have a black belt in regex, so I can probably help you here if you can give an example of the main match and the lookingAt requirements?

Comment: @Bohemian See my answer, I believe i've come up with a solution.

Comment: can't find any source to the mysterious Java regexp lookingAt class that the above libphonenumber uses

Comment: sure @NathanF.  First, the regexp feature lookingAt is non-standard outside of Java and it isn't in Go.  Second, you haven't supplied any code that shows an attempt to solve the problem.  Thirdly, the Go community on SO aggressively downvote *anything* they don't like the smell of.  If you want help with this sort of issue with Go Reddit is a much better place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at a few examples and some other sample Go code, I've come up with a more practical implementation that will also give you the start,end locations that would be available in the Java implementation. You can use the start,end locations to also retrieve the `group` location by using `stringToMatch[start:end]`

```golang
// lookingAt Attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning of the region, against the pattern
// without requiring that the entire region be matched and returns a boolean indicating whether or not the
// pattern was matched and the start and end indexes of where the match was found.
func lookingAt(pattern *regexp.Regexp, stringToMatch string) (bool, int, int) {
    idxs := pattern.FindStringIndex(stringToMatch)
    var matched bool
    var start int = -1
    var end   int = -1

    matched = len(idxs) > 0 && idxs[0] == 0
    if len(idxs) > 0 {
        start = idxs[0]
    }
    if len(idxs) > 1 {
        end = idxs[1]
    }

    return matched, start, end
}
```

#### Example

(Example of `lookingAt` taken from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matcher-lookingat-method-in-java-with-examples/))

**Java**

```java
// Get the regex to be checked 
String regex = "Geeks"; 
  
// Create a pattern from regex 
Pattern pattern 
    = Pattern.compile(regex); 
  
// Get the String to be matched 
String stringToBeMatched 
    = "GeeksForGeeks"; 
  
// Create a matcher for the input String 
Matcher matcher 
    = pattern 
          .matcher(stringToBeMatched); 
  
boolean matched = matcher.lookingAt();
int start = matcher.start();
int end = matcher.end();

if (matched) {
    System.out.println("matched, " + start + " - " + end);
} else {
    System.out.println("not matched");
}
```

In Go:

```golang
regex := "Geeks"
stringToBeMatched := "GeeksForGeeks"

pattern := regexp.MustCompile(regex)
    
matched, start, end := lookingAt(pattern, stringToBeMatched)
    
if matched {
    fmt.Printf("matched, %v - %v\n", start, end)
} else {
    fmt.Println("not matched")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/MjT9uaUY4u3

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash i edited the original question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries...wish you success!